# Title Case a Sentence using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am so close in completing this exercise. The instruction is to convert the str into this new string `Here Is My Handle Here Is My Spout`.

My code is returning exactly `Here Is My Handle Here Is My Spout` but when I tried to `console.log(result.split(" "))` it was returning with this `[ '', 'Here', 'Is', 'My', 'Handle', 'Here', 'Is', 'My', 'Spout' ]` .

I am trying to get rid of the empty string in the index 0 but I can't seem to remove it.
I am also thinking that I am returning the arrays of the `words` when I passed it in the `result` instead of a string?

```
function titleCase(str) {
  const words = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  let result = "";
  for (let word of words) {
let firstCap = word.replace(word[0], word[0].toUpperCase());
 result = result + " " + firstCap;
  }
  console.log(result.split(" "))
  return result;
}

console.log(titleCase("HERE IS MY HANDLE HERE IS MY SPOUT"));
```

Comment: Instead of concatenating to a string, push to a new array, then join it on space.

Comment: Yes I also tried it but I am getting an error when I tried ```result.join(" ")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the line:

```
result = result + " " + firstCap;
```

When `result` has value `""` you should not add a space but rather an empty string as follows:

```
result = result + (result.length ? " " : "") + firstCap;
```

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  const words = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  let result = "";
  for (let word of words) {
    let firstCap = word.replace(word[0], word[0].toUpperCase());
    result = result + (result.length ? " " : "") + firstCap;
  }
  console.log(result.split(" "))
  return result;
}

console.log(titleCase("HERE IS MY HANDLE HERE IS MY SPOUT"));
```

A better approach would be to use `Array#map()` followed by `Array#join()`.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  const words = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  return words.map(word => word.replace(word[0], word[0].toUpperCase())).join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase("HERE IS MY HANDLE HERE IS MY SPOUT"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it better! :)

Comment: Glad you found this to be the **best answer**. If you also found the answer **useful** feel free to **upvote** it (^). Glad I could help. Enjoy!